VLOOKUP IMPORTRANGE to select the column number in another file also
I want to vlookup importrange the data in another file and the specific column number will be selected in the another file because if ever there are changes in the column/field in the main file if will not affect.
Even I added a new column, I want to not affect the column number of the status and remarks field
=Arrayformula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A5:A,IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/165iY-i_BYz5BWOX8ae6lBIh9gPJee0lnfmceCCtzpmM/edit?gid=0#gid=0","Sheet1!A3:H"),**ROW1 SELECTED IN THE SOURCE FILE**,0)))

SOURCE FILE: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x3Upa0qhTItyVjXiNwTaIsbajq4ac4cZsX7Pap27KGE/edit?usp=sharing
TARGET FILE: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/165iY-i_BYz5BWOX8ae6lBIh9gPJee0lnfmceCCtzpmM/edit?gid=0#gid=0

Your target file is not accessible. Please share it as public.

Hi @Harun24hr updated already.

Please [edit] the question and add the sample data (as text) inside it - A question should not depend on external resources in order to be solved

Are you saying STATUS in source will not always be in Column_G? so what should be taken into account: the header_STATUS in Cell_G2 of SOURCE or number 7 in Cell_G1 of SOURCE?!

HELPFUL INFO: Sharing a google sheet and/or screenshots as the only source of test data is not encouraged on Stackoverflow. The recommended method is to provide a sample of test data as markdown table. You can use this tool to create the markdown_format & add it to your question. Here's one example question to get a picture on how its done.

Hi Yes @rockinfreakshow . Even I added a new column, I want to not affect the column number of the status and remarks

Did you also checkout the instructions comment on how to & NOT to share the test data here on Stack?!

Try this:
Using the Match Function to Adjust CHOOSECOLS function. I am updating this answer for future readers. The Goal is to find a specific header and use it as a base for a filter.
=LET(x, IMPORTRANGE("Your Spreadsheet","SHEET1!A1:H"), BYROW(A2:A5, LAMBDA(r, FILTER(HSTACK(CHOOSECOLS(x,MATCH("STATUS",CHOOSEROWS(x,2),0)),CHOOSECOLS(x,MATCH("REMARKS",CHOOSEROWS(x,2),0))),CHOOSECOLS(x,1)=r))))

This formula is based on how long the range is going to be and then, assuming that the one you want to take would be the last column and second to the last column.
Sample output:

Reference:
Match
Filter

Hi Babanana. Not totally the last column and second to the last column. Even I added a new column in between the field, I want to not affect the column number of the status and remarks field

So you just want the 7th and 8th column is this correct? Regardless on what happens on the imported range?

I have updated my answer based on your recent comment.

Not exactly the 7th and 8th column but I want to get the status and remarks column even I added new column in between the column. So im thinking to vlookup importrange the data and column number will be selected in the source file cell above the field of status and remarks

I have another iteration, based on what you have. I have to find where the "REMARKS" and "STATUS" is that correct? If it is you can just use the MATCH to return a value you can use for Choosecols.
